# How to choose an object from multiple objects from a JSON file (Ajax, js)?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, node.js

There is a function that sends an Ajax request to the JSON file, gets the text and places it inside the HTML page.
I need to filter the JSON content to take only a certain **object** (of many objects in the JSON file).

I tried this first, for to get a specific key or parameter from the same object:

```js
 var responseObject = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); 
console.log(responseObject.header);
callback(responseObject.header);
```

Now in the web console, I see the parameter of the key that I need. but on the page this text does not appear.

**Questions:**

- Where is the mistake in the code?
- As I understand, this way I can get the key or it's parameter inside of an object. But what syntax should be to choose an object among several other ones?
- I heard that the same can be done on the server side, could you
  please advise me of any materials on the subject, I just started to
  learn Ajax and NodeJS.

**Whole function (it is written as a commonjs module)**

```js
module.exports = function(jsonDir, templId, finId){
function sendGet(callback) {
    /* create an AJAX request using XMLHttpRequest*/
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    

    /* Specify the type of request by using XMLHttpRequest "open", 
       here 'GET'(argument one) refers to request type
       "jsonDir" (argument two) refers to JSON file location*/
    xhr.open('GET', jsonDir);

    /*Using onload event handler you can check status of your request*/
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
        
            
            var responseObject = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); 
            console.log(responseObject.header);
            callback(responseObject.header);
         
        } else {
            alert(xhr.statusText);
        }
    };

    /*Using onerror event handler you can check error state, if your request failed to get the data*/
    xhr.onerror = function () {
        alert("Network Error");
    };

    /*send the request to server*/
    xhr.send();
}

//For template-1
var dateTemplate = document.getElementById(templId).innerHTML;
var template = Handlebars.compile(dateTemplate);

sendGet(function (response) {
    document.getElementById(finId).innerHTML += template(response);
})
}
```

Comment: Maybe your template is wrong? Did you try adding plain text w/o template?

Comment: @Stan No, it works if I'm not trying to filter content from a JSON file. In this case I see the text on the page.

Comment: @Stan I mean, this is works:  
callback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));

Comment: In callback of sendGet function did you try console.log(response)? Or even console.log(template(response));

Comment: @Molda Thank you for the advice, just tried it, but an error appeared in the web console: ReferenceError: response is not defined

Comment: @Molda Did I understand correctly that you meant this:  `if (xhr.status === 200) { callback(console.log(response)); } else { alert(xhr.statusText);  }`

Comment: No i meant `sendGet(function (response) { console.log(response); });`

Comment: @Molda Okay, thank you. Using `console.log(response)` I got `Object { header: "Powerful business", describtion: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consect…" }`. And using `console.log(template(response));` I got the same + HTML tags that I've added inside the Handlebars Template - `<h1>Powerful business</h1> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec turpis neque, sodales a faucibus at, viverra luctus urna. Suspendisse dignissim neque dui, in tincidunt arcu.</p>`

Comment: @Molda How can I choose only the Header key parameter ("Powerfull business"), to be compiled, with the Handlebars Template? If I will create another object in the JSON file, how can I select the second object to be compiled, but not the first one?

Comment: @MaximVelichkin i'm bit lost at what are you trying to achieve here. If you don't want to pass all of the objects props to template then use `template({header: response.header})`. If this is not what you need try to add your template and possibly show what you have and the result you want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122703/discussion-between-maxim-velichkin-and-molda).